# Como hago para que mi texto de la tabla quede junto?

Tags: html, css

Lo que quiero que la palabra texto quede mas junta al día de la semana para ahorrarme espacio,
creo que es por el container-all, que es en donde esta la tabla porque eso tiene el margin pero quiero conservar ese margin y que quede mas junto el texto al dia, ya intente poniendo el codigo margin: none; en dias, txt y textos pero no funciona y si quito el margin de container-all en css entonces todo queda pegado a la izquierda y no centrado, que puedo usar para mantener la posición de lo que tengo aunque cambie el código el texto quede mas pegado al día de la semana

```css
body{
    background-image: url(patron1.png);
}


.title{

    font-size: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.container-all{
    margin-left: 500px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-right: 500px;
    height: 1750px;
    width: 1000px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.linea{
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: none;
}

.tabla{
    background: wheat;
    margin: 125px;
    border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: none;
}

.dias{
    height: 20%;
    margin: -100px;
}

.txt{
    height: 250px;
    margin: -100px;
}

.textos{
    border: none;
    margin: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link href="StyleIndex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-all">
        <div align="center">
            <p class="title">Titulo</p>
            <hr size="5" color="red" class="linea">
        </div>
        <div>
            <table style="width: 75%; height: 60%;" class="tabla">
                <tr>
                    <th>Lunes</th>
                    <th>Viernes</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="txt"><input type="text" placeholder="texto" class="textos"></th>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Martes</th>
                    <th>Sabado</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Miercoles</th>
                    <th>Domingo</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Jueves</th>
                    <th>texto</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                    <th class="txt">texto</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="ejemplo">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="prueba()">
    <input type="button" id="btn2" onclick="mostrar()">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te entendí bien, en el CSS en la clase `.txt` tenes lo siguiente:

`.txt{ height: 250px; margin: -100px; }`

El height estipulado al `<th>` le da el tamaño y por esa queda lejos.

Comment: entonces no se puede modificar para que quede mas junto?